# Building Cells around Specific latitude and longitue. as attached in picture. (Python, Geopandas)

Tags: python, geopandas

i just want to give input for  Latitude , Longitude, bearing , distance and how much angle it should bt wide.
The Output should look like this.

[Cells Image around sepecific Lat long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9Wph.jpg)

Comment: We need to see the code your trying.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for how to post.

Comment: How are you doing the plotting?

Comment: the snap i shared is from a GIS Software MAPINFO, i want to do the same in python, i have researeched shapely Geopandas alot but unable to reach any conclusion, to how to draw.